# platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js - 404 after updating packages in Angular2 tutorial

Tags: angularjs, angular, npm

I started following Angular2 tutorial a while ago. Now that I've come back to it and got to the [Routing chapter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html), it seems like the tutorial has been updated slightly and I had to go back and update `package.json` to the [current version](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#add-config-files) or the `app.routes.ts` file wouldn't compile. Now it compiles fine but when I run the application, scripts crash at runtime, apparently inside the Zone.js package:

[image]

I've checked and the `platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js` file indeed doesn't exist on disk.

This is the new `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

I've tried using [the longer version from the tutorial's GitHub repository](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json), but the error is the same. Although the vanilla GitHub project builds and runs fine.

I've made sure my `<script`> tags in `index.html` match the ones on GitHub:

```
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
```

My `typings.json` file:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160317120654",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160505161446",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#4.0.0+20160509154515"
  }
}
```

How can I get rid of this error? My Angular2 experience so far consisting in copying code from the tutorial like a monkey, I don't really understand what this error relates to...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Angular2 app was not able to load `platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js` as well as your other umd bundles [as they were moved](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-2) to the `bundles/` subdirectory in `2.0.0-rc.2`.

As you already noticed your error was inside your `system.config.js` as it was trying to load the umd bundles using the wrong path ([see here](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/src/systemjs.config.js#L43)).

Copying the new config file should have added the `'/bundles/' +` part which does resolve your issue.

Comment: How you can copy this file? I mean from where to where? Manually?

Answer (score 1):

I had to monkey-copy `system.config.js` as well: https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/src/systemjs.config.js

Comment: Do you still want an explanation why it didn't work before? I was just starting to write an answer.

Comment: @Jonas Sure, it would be great to understand what's going on in this file. I'll accept your answer if it's better than the shity one of mine.

Answer (score 1):

`node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

> ```
> index.html:18 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:51412/src/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js
> Error: XHR error (404 Not Found)
> ```

Well, I came across the above issues. To fix it, delete browser cache and hit f5 in the visual studio.